# mysql contradictory queries to run simultaneously

Tags: mysql

I'm having problem working around the logic on how to build a particular query.

What I have is a form that narrows housing listings down by things like number of bedrooms, sq ft, etc.

My issue is writing a query that includes both city and zip code parameters along with the details of the house.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM my_houses 
    WHERE 
        BEDROOMS >= 3 
    AND 
        SQFT >= 1500 
    AND
        CITY IN ('Gotham', 'Metropolis', 'Central')
```

VS

```
SELECT * FROM my_houses 
    WHERE 
        BEDROOMS >= 3 
    AND 
        SQFT >= 1500 
    AND
        CITY IN ('Gotham', 'Metropolis', 'Central')
    OR
        ZIP IN ('65656', '65432', '63254')
```

Now, as I understand it, when I use `OR` it doesn't put the other paraments against `ZIP`, so it will show all entries with those `ZIP` values, regardless of number of bedrooms.  Also that cities and ZIP's are a little mutually exclusive, so there would be a conflict with something meeting a `CITY` value but not a `ZIP` and thus would be excluded.  But, if I can separate them out, that shouldn't matter.

Is there a way to get around this without writing two sub queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logically group your OR with parenthesis... something like...

```
WHERE 
        BEDROOMS >= 3 
    AND 
        SQFT >= 1500 
    AND
        (  CITY IN (Gotham, Metropolis, Central)
          OR
           ZIP IN (65656, 65432, 63254) )
```

However, your city and ZIP values would be expected within quotes such as

```
          CITY IN ( 'Gotham', 'Metropolis', 'Central')
          ZIP IN ('65656', '65432', '63254' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parens to group your or clause.  That way, if either one is true, it will satisfy the `AND`

```
SELECT * FROM my_houses 
WHERE 
    BEDROOMS >= 3 
AND 
    SQFT >= 1500 
AND
(
    CITY IN (Gotham, Metropolis, Central)
OR
    ZIP IN (65656, 65432, 63254)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the brackets :)

```
SELECT * FROM my_houses 
WHERE 
    BEDROOMS >= 3 
AND 
    SQFT >= 1500 
AND (
    CITY IN (Gotham, Metropolis, Central)
    OR
    ZIP IN (65656, 65432, 63254)
    )
```